# storing datagrid values into database on cell_leave event

Tags: c#, datagrid

I'm trying to store data grid entire row value in database,my data grid has 4 columns(combobox column,2textbox columns,checkbox column),i am firing cell leave event in the 3rd column of data grid,and storing entire row values into data base,but i;m not getting edited value of last cell and getting an exception ,Here is my code

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if ( dataGridView1.CurrentCell == dataGridView1[dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 2, dataGridView1.RowCount - 1])
        {                
            try
            {
                SqlParameter p1, p2, p3, p4, p5;
                p1 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@tid", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
                p1.Value = dataGridView1.Rows[j - 1].Cells[0].Value;
                MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Rows[j - 1].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                p2 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@uid", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
                p2.Value = "D";

                p3 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@timespent", SqlDbType.Time);
                p3.Value = dataGridView1.Rows[j - 1].Cells[1].Value;
                MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Rows[j - 1].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                p4 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@taskdate", SqlDbType.Date, 20);
                p4.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
                p5 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@status", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
                p5.Value = dataGridView1.Rows[j-1].Cells[2].Value;
                MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Rows[j - 1].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("successfully Entered");
                con1.Close();
```

Comment: What is the exception _exactly_? On which line?

Comment: i'm not getting value into p5 so i'm getting "OBJECT NOT SET TO AN INSTANCE OF OBJECT",as cell leave event is fired in that particular cell which i'm assigning to p5,i need the modified value though leave event is fired that cell

Comment: [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: i need the modified value of cell from which cell_leave event is fired